# Framer Motion AnimatePresence Double Rendering on Exit Animation

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, framer-motion

I am running into a seriously weird problem. I am using NextJs and Framer Motion and Tailwind. So I have a list of Cards and when you click one, it animates to a middle position on the screen, and when you click again it falls back in line. The problem is when you click the same card again, the animation double renders on the exit for some reason. Here is a video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=78fbZmVXrho

This does not happen when I remove the AnimatePresence component but I want it to have an exit animation so I need to fix this.

Here is a code sample (I am excluding the Card component because that does not have any issues from what I can tell). The "Item" component is what double renders:

```
export function List({
    selectedId,
    setSelectedId,
}: {
    selectedId: string | null;
    setSelectedId: any;
}) {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <div className="w-full max-w-5xl flex-[1_1_100%] py-11 px-6">
                <ul className="flex flex-wrap content-start">
                    {items.map((card) => (
                        <Card
                            key={card.id}
                            {...card}
                            selectedId={selectedId}
                            setSelectedId={setSelectedId}
                        />
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
            <AnimatePresence>
                {selectedId && (
                    <Item
                        id={selectedId}
                        key="item"
                        setSelectedId={setSelectedId}
                    />
                )}
            </AnimatePresence>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}


export function Item({
    id,
    setSelectedId,
}: {
    id: string;
    setSelectedId: any;
}) {
    const item = items.find((item) => item.id === id) as Item;

    const { title, category, image } = item;

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <motion.div
                initial={{ opacity: 0 }}
                animate={{ opacity: 1 }}
                exit={{ opacity: 0, transition: { duration: 0.15 } }}
                transition={{ duration: 0.2, delay: 0.15 }}
                style={{ pointerEvents: "auto" }}
                className="overlay z-[1]"
            >
                <div onClick={() => setSelectedId(null)}></div>
            </motion.div>
            <motion.div
                className="card-content-container open"
                transition={{ duration: 0.5 }}
            >
                <motion.div
                    className="card-content z-[1001]"
                    layout
                    layoutId={`card-container-${id}`}
                >
                    <motion.div
                        className="card-image-container"
                        layoutId={`card-image-container-${id}`}
                    >
                        <Image
                            className="card-image"
                            src={image.src}
                            alt=""
                            fill
                            priority
                            onClick={() => setSelectedId(null)}
                        />
                    </motion.div>
                    <motion.div
                        className="title-container"
                        layoutId={`title-container-${id}`}
                    >
                        <span className="category">{category}</span>
                        <h2>{title}</h2>
                    </motion.div>
                    <motion.div
                        className="content-container"
                        layoutId={`content-container-${id}`}
                    >
                        <LoremIpsum
                            p={1}
                            avgWordsPerSentence={5}
                            avgSentencesPerParagraph={2}
                        />
                    </motion.div>
                </motion.div>
            </motion.div>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

I borrowed liberally from this sandbox and it works perfectly fine there so I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong: https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animatesharedlayout-app-store-demo-forked-h556x?file=/src/styles.css